# Transferring Mail data from one MBP to an other

Tags: macos, email, migration

I try to transfer my mails, preferences and all settings from one Mac to an other. Both are using the most recent Mavericks OS X.

I copied the ~/Library/Mail directory from the old one, as well as the ~/Library/preferences/com.apple.mail.* files. The 3 accounts seems to be working fine, and it appears, as if some of the mails have been transferred indeed, but I certainly miss the whole "ON MY MAC" folder structure form the new setup.

What is missing, where is that information stored?

Answer (score 1):

In Mail.app in the "Mailboxes" section on the left side, (where Sent and Junk folders are) look toward the bottom of all the folders; there should be `Smart Mailboxes` and below that `On My Mac` folders.

It seems that some people are finding that it's hidden after they've upgraded to OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Next to "On My Mac" you should be a small "show/hide" as you hover over it with the mouse cursor. If you click on that hopefully you'll see those items once again.

Comment: It is not the case unfortunately. It is shown, and I can even see some default folders there (Junk folders, Recovered messages from different accounts etc), but not the others...

Answer (score 1):

I did multiple things in parallel and finally it works:

- removed all Mails from the new MBP (~/Library/Mail/*)
- removed all preferences from the new MBP (~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail*)
- rebuilt the mailboxes on the old MBP
- copied everything once more
- after a restart, now it's working

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

copy the containers from the old to the new MBP

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.MailServiceAgent
```

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere on the Apple forums about this tip.

I wanted to configure my mail account from scratch, in Mavericks, sync the remote e-mails by IMAP and then import the local e-mails. Since I forgot to use the export function in Mail, before installing Mavericks, I just copied the old local `mbox` over, but Mail wouldn't automatically pick it up, and using the import function on the same folder, simply didn't import anything.

So, to get my old local `On My Mac > Archive` folder I

1. Quit Mail.app
2. Copied `Archive.mbox` from a backup to `~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes`
3. Deleted from `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData` the following items

   - Envelope Index
   - Envelope Index-shm
   - Envelope Index-wal
4. Relaunched Mail.app and proceed with the importing wizard
5. Renamed the newly imported folder to `Archive` (until renamed the e-mails show up as blank)

Here, `Archive` is just my example `mbox`, substitute with yours.